# Pass my local environment variables values to my ec2 user data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, vault

As simple as it sounds, I would like to pass my local environment variable value inside my ec2 user data script. So for instance I run this locally:

```
export PASSWORD=mypassword
printenv PASSWORD
mypassword
```

then once I ssh to my ec2 and run

```
printenv PASSWORD
```

I should see the same value `mypassword`. I haven't found a way to inject the right codes in my user data script. Please help if you can.

This is my user data, I am basically installing some packages then authenticate to my vault with the password value I would like to upload from my laptop to my ec2. I just don't want to hardcode `mypassword` in my user dat script. (not even sure if it's doable?)

```
 # User Data for ASG
  user_data = <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

set -x -v

exec > >(tee -i user-data.log 2>/dev/console) 2>&1

# Install latest AWS cli
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install --update


# Install VAULT cli
sudo wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/1.8.2/vault_1.8.2_linux_amd64.zip
sudo unzip vault_1.8.2_linux_amd64.zip 
sudo mv vault /usr/local/bin/vault
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/vault
vault -v

# Vault env var
export VAULT_ADDR=https://myvault.test
export VAULT_SKIP_VERIFY=true
export VAULT_NAMESPACE=test

# Vault login (to authenticate to vault must export local value of $PASSWORD
export VAULT_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
vault login -namespace=test -method=userpass username=myuser password=$VAULT_PASSWORD
```

Comment: This works, so the only difference I can see is you're using UPPERCASE, `export no_proxy=localhost`, does this work `export passwrd=mypassword` ?

Comment: Can you show how you're creating the instance and passing the userdata script? Userdata script only runs on first instance launch.

Comment: What are you doing between "run this locally" and "once I ssh to my ec2"?

Comment: @JeremyThompson I added the user data. If I understand what you say I have to run `export no_proxy=localhost` first  in order to see the expected value of `export PASSWORD=mypassword` which is `mypassword`?

Comment: Still not sure what you can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by setting up locally all variables for my sensitive data and defined them my `variables.tf`. Then on my user data field I just exported the TF var name. See below:

Local setup

```
export TF_VAR_password=password
```

TF code --> `variables.tf`

```
variable "password" {
  description = "my password"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}
```

Now in my app user data script

```
export MYPASSWORD=${var.password}
```

VOILA :)

Here is the website as a point of reference --> https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/sensitive-variables?in=terraform/0-14  ( look for **Set values with environment variables**)

Answer (score 1):

`user_data` runs under `root` user and it **has its own shell environment**. Thus when you `ssh` to the instance as an `ec2-user` or `ubuntu`, you have your own, different local environment. This is the reason why your `export` does not work.

To rectify the issue, your `user_data` **must modify** `.bashrc` (or equivalent depending on the OS) of your ssh user (often `ec2-user` or `ubuntu`). Only then your exports will take effect.